# Write a Test case with junit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

What ist the correct way to write a test case with Junit for this SetScene Methode?

```
public static void SetScene(int index){
  root.getChildren().remove(liste.get(indexcurrent));
  root.getChildren().add(liste.get(index));
  indexcurrent=index;


    if (index == 3) {
        try {
            root.setCenter(liste.get(index));
        }
        catch (Exception InvocationTargetException){
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: No. Actually i can not understand that.

Comment: Sorry I answered wrong first. Then I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like

1. Prepare `root` with children
2. Call `SetScene(x)`
3. Inspect `root` and `currentindex` for required values and state.